# Wipe entire windows OS from all disks to boot linux

Tags: linux, system-installation

I have been running Linux in a dual booting setup and on a separate machine for around 6 months now. I have found my brother's old computer and have been given permission to wipe it and put in Linux.

I was wondering how I can completely erase all trace of Windows from my SSD so I can boot it with a USB.

Comment: most Linux installation disks have an option that wipes the whole disk and installs Linux by default. Or just open gparted and delete all the partitions

Comment: You can boot from USB without wiping the SSD (if USB boot is supported on that system).

Comment: You may have to disable secure boot before you can get your machine to boot Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you do not need to wipe Windows first. Just plug in bootable USB and reboot.

If your computer still boots up in Windows - reboot again and open BIOS setup (you would have to press Del, F2, Ctrl+ESC or something other during the POST, it should be written on POST screen). In the BIOS setup menu, find Boot Order and make the USB number one. Reboot once more.

If your computer older than 15 years (approximately, do not remember when USB boot become a standard) - it is possible, that there is no USB in a boot sequence or even booting from USB at all. In that case you would have to play with a CD or even floppy disks. Yes, such museum-age hardware still exists.

After you boot from USB you can open Partition Editor (some kind of it definitely will be present on USB designed to be bootable). And you would be able to easily wipe any previous OS from SSD/HDD.